# GitLab fails on install and/or reconfigure

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

For a college assignment I had to configure gitlab on my virtual machine that’s hosted on google cloud engine and is currently running Ubuntu 20.04.
I tried to install gitlab twice but the install fails (first it got stuck for at least 5 minutes on unpacking github-ce (13.10.2-ce.0) then it failed.

Reconfiguring gets me the same message but without any context, I don’t know where the error is, what is causing it and how to fix it.

I did research this error but the only thing that I found out is that it’s probably related with the config file. Only line in my config line that’s not commented out is the external url and it has a value so I have no idea what to do.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess something on the machine is fup. Try the same on a known-good new machine / fresh install.

> Ubunut 20.04

Sounds like a fun OS.